# Get the maximum sizeof at compile time c++03

Tags: c++, c++03

I need to calculate at compile time the maximum size of four structs, to be used as an array size.

I wonder if I can do something like:

```
#define MAX_SIZE_OF_STRUCTS MY_DESIRED_MAX_MACRO (sizeof(strcut1_type),
                                                  sizeof(strcut2_type), 
                                                  sizeof(strcut3_type), 
                                                  sizeof(strcut4_type))

int my_array[MAX_SIZE_OF_STRUCTS];
```

Is there a macro(that looks like `MY_DESIRED_MAX_MACRO`) or something else (like operators) that can do the job?
Maybe `#define` is not the better way I think it could be done using `const int` but I'm not sure which is the better alternative.

**[EDIT]**: The purpose of this is to reserve space in static buffers to copy it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks, That's a great alternative, I will try to implement it as you sugested.

Comment: Are you trying to declare a 4-D array or an array that is the size of the largest structure?

Comment: @cup an array that is the size of the largest structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very nice, but assuming you define

```
#define MY_MAX(A,B) (((A)>(B))?(A):(B))
```

and since all your `sizeof` are compile time constants (since [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s do not exist in C++03)

You might use

```
#define MAX_SIZE_OF_STRUCT \
  MY_MAX(MY_MAX(sizeof(strcut1_type),sizeof(strcut2_type),\
         MY_MAX(sizeof(strcut3_type),sizeof(strcut4_type))
```

(that would be [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)-expanded to a huge *constant* expression that the compiler would [constant-fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding))

Of course, that trick won't scale well if you have a dozen of `strcut`*i*`_type`

Maybe you could compute the `sizeof` some fictious `union`, e.g.

```
union fictious_un {
 strcut1_type s1;
 strcut2_type s2; 
 strcut3_type s3; 
 strcut4_type s4;
};
```

then have

```
#define MAX_SIZE_OF_STRUCT sizeof(union fictious_un)
```

which scales slightly better, but does not compute exactly the same thing (e.g. because of gaps or alignment issues).

However, you did not explain why you need this. You might need to take care of alignment issues manually elsewhere.

Comment: I realy like your second alternative! Thank you very much!

Comment: The purpose of this is to reserve space in static buffers to copy it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without macros, something like this:

```
template< typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4 > class
largest_of4
{
    union inner
    {
        char v1[sizeof(T1)];
        char v2[sizeof(T2)];
        char v3[sizeof(T3)];
        char v4[sizeof(T4)];
    };

    char dummy[sizeof(inner)];
};

assert(19 == sizeof(largest_of4< char, char[19], double, void * >));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's is a great answer too!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do the same thing is with a union. Then do a sizeof the union.

```
union thirteen {
 a strcut1_type;
 b strcut2_type;
 c strcut3_type;
 d strcut4_type;
};

int tag; // An integer to describe which on is active.
 union thirteen myunion;
```

Usually the tag is put inside a struct for clarity.

```
struct mystruct {
    int tag;
    union thirteen myunion;
};
struct mystuct myvalues;
```

Comment: Thanks! this is usefull too!